# How to judge the function type according to the parameter type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the following case, How to judge the function type according to the parameter `b` type

```
const getData = (a: string, b?: string) => {
  const obj: Record<string, string> = JSON.parse(a)
  if (b) {
    return obj[b]
  }
  return obj
}

const c = getData("{'kind':'cs'}")  
const d = getData("{'kind':'cs'}", 'kind')
```

Expected:

```
const c = getData("{'kind':'cs'}")  // result: {kind: cs}  type:  c => Record<string, string>
const d = getData("{'kind':'cs'}", 'kind') // result: cs  type: d => string
```

Actual

```
const c = getData("{'kind':'cs'}")  // result: {kind: cs}  type:  c => Record<string, string> | string
const d = getData("{'kind':'cs'}", 'kind') // result: cs  type: d => Record<string, string> | string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Function overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) syntax of typescript.

```
function getData(a: string): Record<string, string>;
function getData(a: string, b: string): string;

function getData(a: string, b?: string) {
  const obj: Record<string, string> = JSON.parse(a);
  if (b) {
    return obj[b];
  }
  return obj;
}

const c = getData("{'kind':'cs'}");
const d = getData("{'kind':'cs'}", "kind");
```